# User name and password for dynamic BizTalk MSMQ send port cannot be set

Tags: dynamic, port, biztalk, msmq, send

I have just discovered interesting thing. 
In BizTalk MSMQ send adapter you can set up Logon Info by providing User Name and Password to access the remote queue. But these properties (User Name and Password) do not exist in adapter class. I.e. when you construct message to be sent in orchestration you set up adapter properties, like this: deliveryMsg(MSMQ.BodyType) = 30; So there is no such things as User Name or Password properties in MSMQ adapter.
This means you cannot specify a user you want to use for MSMQ dynamic port.
Has anyone ever come across this issue? I can't beleive Microsoft did not include these properties by mistake. Any solution for that?

Thank you
Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue before, and yes, you are correct that username and password are not available in the [property schema of BizTalk's MSMQ adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577593(v=bts.80).aspx) to set dynamically. I even decompiled the Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.MSMQ.MsmqAdapterProperties.dll, just to make sure that those two properties were absent.

The username and password are considered sensitive, so it makes sense for those properties to be encrypted. So Microsoft probably chose to store them in the Enterprise SSO database, instead of with the other, "normal" adapter properties. For some reason they did not then take the extra steps of making it possible to set the username/password properties dynamically.

For what it's worth, I have also found it frustrating that the MSMQ adapter does not allow you to set [the message label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.label(v=vs.110).aspx) or [the message extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725319/how-do-i-set-the-msmq-message-extension-using-biztalks-msmq-adapter). It seems like a lot of functionality was left out of this particular adapter.

Comment: Thank you Schellack. But this doesn't make sence as other adapters have user name and password properties exposed. Such as FTP, SFTP, File, etc. On another note, I found the following description for the property User Name of the MSMQ adapter in Microsoft documentation: "You cannot use the local user of the remote computer for the user name." Well... then what user can I use? Domain? But what if the remote machine is not in the sender's domain? What user should I use then?

Comment: You are right that other adapters allow you to dynamically set the username, etc. I can only speculate as to why Microsoft didn't enable that functionality with the MSMQ adapter. When you need to enter a username in the MSMQ adapter config, you can prefix the username with the domain you want to use, e.g., `DomainName\UserName`

Comment: Thanks again. I really appreciate your quick responses. In my case the remote server is not in any domain, it's in the workgroup. I guess Microsoft didn't think about this possibility :)